# How to use view models for windows inside a DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF. Here is xaml defining a window defined inside a DLL:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        d1p1:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:attachedProperties="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.AttachedProperties"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.ViewModels"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VmLocator}}"
        Title="{Binding MyVm.MyTitle, Mode=OneTime}" Height="300" Width="460">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModels:ViewModelLocatorTestSteps x:Key="VmLocator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

When the client code constructs this window object, this exception is thrown:

```
Cannot find resource named 'VmLocator'
```

How do I define the resource earlier so that it exists when it is needed? I'd also prefer the solution enable Intellisense to work. This is my first attempt at a window defined inside a DLL.

Using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Window to create its own DataContext, you can just stick that in the constructor in the code-behind, and avoid the necessity of making your VmLocator a resource.  The resources of a WPF control (including a Window) are available to children of that control.

just:

```
 public MyNamespace()
 {
     InitializeComponents();
     this.DataContext = new VmLocator();
 }
```

If you really want to make your DataContext a resource, you could create an application-level resource and reference that.

Also - 'MyNamespace' is a very confusing name for a class :)

Comment: Modified example. Actual namespace and name are quite long :)

Comment: Both of your suggestions fixed the exception. I actually do use an app-level resource for the windows defined in my EXE, but when I added another one there for the current issue and reference it in my DLL-level window XAML, Visual Studio 2013 flags "VmLocator" as "not found" and I lose intellisense.Same happens when I construct the VM in the code behind. In my main windows (in the EXE).neither problem occurs. Is there a way to implement this that doesn't do that?

Comment: I'm not really sure - I generally disregard when the xaml editor/designer loses its marbles, since it seems to have so little correlation with actual runtime behavior.